# Relation between matrix eigenvalues and pre and post multiplication

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

So I have a matrix $A\in\Re^{6\times6}$, in my problem I have a matrix $X\in\Re^{6\times 4}$ the interesting fact is that the eigenvalues of $A$ are 6 clearly, now if I perform this operation:
$$B=X^T A X$$

I find out that the eigenvalues of $B$ are 4 eigenvalues of $A$ (and 2 eigenvalues of course are lost).
Any tips about how to understand which relation I do have between $A$ and $X$?

Comment: Does X satisfy $X^TX=I$, with $I$ the identity?

Comment: Your $B$ is $4\times 4$ matrix, so it will have 4 eigenvalues. And I guess your $X$ is semi-orthogonal matrix, i.e. $XX^T=I$ or $X^TX=I$, in that case $\mathrm{eig}(B)=\mathrm{eig}(X^TAX)=\mathrm{eig}(A)$, so 4 eigenvalues of $A$ will become 4 eigenvalues of $B$

Comment: Think it as linear transformation from R⁶*⁶ to R⁴*⁴, defined by T(A) = XᵗAX, for some fixed X in R⁶*⁴.

Comment: @NeitherNor yes. It does. While Lee statement about $XX^T=I$ is not verified.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you construct $X$ using any 4 orthogonal eigenvector of $A$ , then it's possible.